# How can one tell that if $(f\circ x)_u a+(f\circ x)_v b$ is differentiable, then $a,b$ are both differentiable?

Tags: differential-geometry

Here differentiable means indefinitely differentiable. Let $f:U\subset S\to \mathbb{R}$ be any function on a regular surface $S$ differentiable in $U$ and $x:V\subset \mathbb{R}^2\to U\subset S$ be a parametrization of $S$. Note that there need not be $x(V)=U$. My question is that if $a,b:V\to \mathbb{R}$ satisfies that the function $F:V\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by

$$ F(u,v)=(f\circ x)_u a(u,v)+(f\circ x)_vb(u,v)$$

is differentiable in $V$ for all differentiable $f$, then can one conclude that $a,b$ are both differentiable? I  know that if $x(V)=U$ then this is true since we can define $f$ by $f(x(u,v))=u$ or $v$ so that $F=a$ and $F=b$ respectively, but when $x(V)\neq U$ I see no guarantee that such $f|_{x(V)}$ can be extended to a differentiable function over $U$.

The original question I'm working on is Ddo Carmo, section 3-4, Exercise 7.
[image]

I encountered this issue when proving that if $w(f)$ is differentiable for all differentiable $f$ then $w$ is differentiable.

Any hint or solution is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just cover $U$ by such open sets $x(V)$.

Comment: @TedShifrin How can such cover extend $f|_{x(V)}$ to the whole $U$?

Comment: This is why partitions of unity are a powerful tool. Personally, I think you're approaching the problem wrong. Being differentiable is a *local* condition, so you just have to check it in a coordinate chart around an arbitrary point $p\in U$.

Comment: @TedShifrin I think you are not getting me right. The assumption is that $w(f)$ is differentiable for all differentiable $f$ in $U$, so for differentiable $f$ defined only in a coordinate chart, $w(f)$ may not be differentiable. That's why we have to see if $f$ could be extended to the whole $U$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that doCarmo does not seem to have thought through this problem at the level of this textbook. You do need the tool of a "bump function," which he does not introduce at this level.

Define 
$$\phi(x) = \begin{cases} e^{-1/x}, & x>0 \\ 0, & x\le 0\end{cases}.$$ 
Then you can check that $\phi$ is smooth, with all derivatives $0$ at $x=0$. Now set $\psi(x) = \dfrac{\int_0^x \phi(t)\phi(1-t)\,dt}{\int_0^1\phi(t)\phi(1-t)\,dt}$. Note that $\psi$ is smooth, $\psi(x)=0$ for $x\le 0$ and $\psi(x)=1$ for $x\ge 1$.

You have a function defined on $V\subset\Bbb R^2$ (namely, $F(u,v)=u$). (Set $B(0,r) = \{u\in\Bbb R^2: \|u\|<r\}$.) Let's assume that $0\in B(0,r)\subset V$ and $x(0)=p$. We will multiply $F$ by an appropriate function $\rho$ that has the properties that $\rho=1$ on $B(0,r/2)$ and $\rho=0$ outside $B(0,r)$. Then the function $(\rho F)\circ x^{-1}$ will extend to be a smooth function everywhere on $U$, which is equal to $f=F\circ x^{-1}$ in a neighborhood of $p$ and $0$ outside $x(B(0,r))$. It remains to build $\rho$ out of $\psi$. Can you do that?

Comment: Thanks! Let the norm be induced by the square metric then $\rho$ would have very neat expression: $\rho(u,v)=\psi(2-\frac{2u}{r})\psi(2-\frac{2v}{r})$.